# Serializer field with source is not present in validated_data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have added a field in serializer with source, Its validate function is being called, but its value is not present in validated_data.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # some fields
    new_name_field = serializers.CharField(source='model_field', required=False)
    # I have renamed this because I need "new_name_field" on my frontend.

    def validate_new_name_field(self, value):
        # do validations
        return value
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        print(attrs['new_name_field'])       # This throws KeyError
```

What am I doing wrong and How do I get the value of new_name_field in my validate function?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `required=False` it won't be present in `attrs` in `validate` function if you haven't passed it.

If this entity exists already, you can access it using `self.instance`. So you can access existing value by `self.instance.model_field`.